# Abort trap :6 Error in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to programming so forgive me if question sounds trivial.Your any suggestion will be a great help in my learning.
I am writing up a Selection_Sorting program on the array of size 10. I am able to compile the program but after giving the input its reflecting this
message:
The sorted array as follows:
   Abort trap: 6

My question is where to look in the program to troubleshoot the issue and what are the reasons this issue occurs ?

For reference I am attaching my code.

```
# include <iostream>
void fill_array(int sample_array[10], int size);
void sort(int sample_array[10], int size);
void swap(int &a1, int &a2);
int index_of_smallest(int array[10], int start_index, int size);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int array[10];
    fill_array(array, 10);
    sort(array, 10);
    cout << " The sorted array as follows : \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}

void fill_array(int sample_array[10], int size)
{
    using namespace std;
    for (int index = 0; index< 10; index++)
    {
        cin >> sample_array[index];
    }
}

void swap(int &a1, int &a2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = a1;
    a1 = a2;
    a2 = temp;
}

int index_of_smallest(int array[10], int start_index, int size)
{
    int min = array[start_index];
    int min_index = start_index;
    for (int i = start_index + 1; i< size - 1; i++)
    {
        if (array[i]< min)
        {
            min = array[i];
            min_index = i;
        }
    }
    return min_index;
}

void sort(int sample_array[10], int size)
{
    int next_min_index;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        next_min_index = index_of_smallest(sample_array, j, 10);
    }
    swap(sample_array[j], sample_array[next_min_index]);
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend that you look at a few coding examples and learn how to lay out your code with indentation so that humans can read it.  Then, feel free to ask a human.  Or, use a debugger like *gdb* to trace the exact line in your program where the error is caught.

Comment: You ought to thank Barmak for taking the time to lay out your code for you.  Try to absorb this into your coding practice so that you always lay it out as you type.  Now that it's readable, I see there's also a logical error in `index_of_smallest`.  The loop termination condition should be `i < size`, and _not_ `i < size - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to decipher the one function that would be most likely at fault.  I've re-formatted it here to be readable:

```
void sort( int sample_array[10], int size )
{
    int next_min_index;
    int j;
    for( j = 0; j < size; j++ )
    {
        next_min_index = index_of_smallest( sample_array, j, 10 );
    }
    swap( sample_array[j], sample_array[next_min_index] );
}
```

And now, hopefully you can see the problem.

The swap is not happening inside the loop.  You moved the definition for `j` out of the loop scope (presumably to fix compile errors you didn't understand, which would have pointed you to the problem).

The swap is happening when `j == 10`.  That is outside your array bounds and your program baulks.  You should fix the error if you change the function to this:

```
void sort( int sample_array[10], int size )
{
    for( int j = 0; j < size; j++ )
    {
        int next_min_index = index_of_smallest( sample_array, j, 10 );
        swap( sample_array[j], sample_array[next_min_index] );
    }
}
```

This might not be the only problem, but I'm not going to decipher the rest of your code.  Hopefully this fix plus some strong encouragement to use human-readable code layout will help you along your way.

Comment: Thank you paddy !! For your words I will keep them in mind for my endeavor in programming.